# Email address is becoming numbers in final output

Tags: powershell

```
$MainResults = $null
[array]$MainResults = $GSuspend | ForEach-Object {
    $License = $null
    foreach ($License in $GoogleLicenses) {  
        If ($License.primaryEmail -eq $_.primaryEmail) {
            If ($License.licenses -contains '1010020020' ) {
                If ($ChangedToArchive -lt $TotalRemainArchive) {
                    $EmailAddress = $null
                    $EmailAddress = $_.primaryEmail
                    gam update user $EmailAddress archived on 
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Email = $EmailAddress
                        Error = $LASTEXITCODE
                    }
                    $ChangedToArchive++
                    $TotalRemainArchive - 1
                    $TotalRemainMain + 1
                }
                ELse {
                    $ArchiveOverFlow++
                }
                Break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the `$EmailAddress` value and it is correct but my final output is as follows below. Also if I comment out the `Gam` command above the `$mainResults` is fine.

Something is happening to the object even though the `$emailAddress` information is fine.

```
*
44
34
38
38
35
34
40
38
34
```

I added the `$EmailAddress` variable in attempt to stop the problem but now I don't know what to do. Ideas ?

Comment: These 2 variables are stdout: `$TotalRemainArchive - 1` & `$TotalRemainMain + 1` which are then captured in `[array]$MainResults =` at first glance this could be an indicator of the problem

Comment: Interesting. That makes sense. Anyway for me to stop that?

Comment: As a troubleshooting step you could add `Write-Host "$($TotalRemainArchive - 1)"` and same for the other var so that at least this output goes to the host and not captured. Still not sure, there is not enough information to help you

Comment: @dcaz *"Anyway for me to stop that?"* simply comment out those lines, they do nothing else than outputing

Comment: I use the numbers later on in the script. Those numbers tell me what Is left.
@Cid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty much given in the comments. The adding and subtracting was going into the `$MainResults` due to stdout:.

I changed the code to

```
 $ChangedToArchive++
 $TotalRemainArchive--
 $TotalRemainMain++
```

And the final result is good.